# Node.js writable stream is hanging

Tags: node.js, async-await, stream

When the number of writes is small (about 10) the end of the response is reached. When the number of writes exceeds 1000 then the `res.end()` is not reached and the request is pending. What is the problem?

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const connection = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'mydb',
  user: 'mydb_user',
  password: 'abcdef'
};
const db = pgp(connection);

const handler = async (req, res, next) => {

  res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

  for (let i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 500; j++) {
      let db_result = await db.any(`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_id = ${i} AND bar_id = ${j};`);
      res.cork();
      res.write(JSON.stringify(db_result[0]));
      process.nextTick(() => res.uncork());
    }
  }

  res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem. Inside the inner for loop i was logging the db_result. Have a look [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1741)